# What's the idiomatic way to add a calculated column to multiple data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few dataframes, let's call them `rates, sensors` with `"session_start"`, `"value_timestamp"` (timestamps) and `"value"` (float) columns. I want to add an `"elapsed"` column, which I've done successfully using the following code:

```
def add_elapsed_min(df):
  df["elapsed"] = (
    df["value_timestamp"] - df["session_start"].min()
  ).dt.total_seconds() / 60.0

for df in [rates, sensors]:
  add_elapsed_min(df)
```

Now, this code does work, and the elapsed column is correct. The minor problem is that I keep getting the `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I've tried changing the code as suggested by the warning, tried adding a `contextlib.suppress`, but can't seem to remove this warning. This makes me think I must be breaking some idiomatic way to do this. So I'm wondering: **If you want to add a calculated column to many dataframes at once, how are you supposed to do this?**

Comment: I can't reproduce the warning. Which version of Pandas do you use?

Comment: I also cannot recreate this issue on 1.5.3. What if you use `df.insert()` instead?

Comment: I'm not currently at my workstation, but I'm using PyCharm community, pyenv with a local python of 3.11.3, and a venv, so whichever pandas that would entail (maybe I'm too much on the bleeding edge here). I'll edit the question with a more complete minimal example when I can give you the version that produces the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I cannot create your warning in Pandas 1.5.3 and considering using `.loc` does not suppress the warning for you, one other option is to use `df.insert` instead.

```
def add_elapsed_min(df):
  elapsed = (df["value_timestamp"] - df["session_start"].min()) / 60.0
  df.insert(df.shape[1], 'elapsed', elapsed)

for df in [rates, sensors]:
  add_elapsed_min(df)
```

Comment: I tried using a temporary variable like this, and the warning actually appears on the `elapsed =` line. I wonder if it's related to the df being part of an iterator?

Comment: That is pretty interesting. I only did that to make it a bit more readable but I received no warnings. What happens if you add the calculation directly to `insert`?

Comment: df.insert worked! Still very odd, but I did realize that it wasn't the temporary that was the problem, but the actual assignment.